# PHP: How to get timestamp when you only have H:i format

Tags: php

Im working with an API that is returning times as H:i (e.g. 19:33) but what I need to know is how to get the unix timestamp for that value and also to find out if the time goes into tomorrow i.e 00:00 would be the next day from 19:33

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: See my answer, and Jon's note. :-)

Answer (score 1):

strtotime() can probably do this:

```
$api_time = some_api_call();

$timestamp = strtotime("today $api_time");

if ($timestamp < (time()-60)) { 
   $timestamp = strtotime("tomorrow $api_time");
}
```

Comment: Your `strtotime` won't work correctly, you need to move the `$api_time` (which would be the `19:33` in the question) with `today`. It should be `$timestamp = strtotime("today $api_time");` Nice elegant answer though. ^^  EDIT: Also need to change the other one to `$timestamp = strtotime("tomorrow $api_time");`

Comment: Yeah, looks like I didn't verify the exact values of the return timestamps.  Fixed ... thanks. :)